# Validating Client Certificate Using Config vs Code and Error "At least one security token in the message could not be validated"

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, validation, ssl

I am trying to validate that the certificate sent with https requests to my web service matches specific a specific certificate in my server's Trusted People store.

The client is signing their soap messages using a private key and I am attempting to use the public key they provided to validate.

If I change:

```
<clientCertificate>
  <authentication certificateValidationMode="None" />
</clientCertificate>
```

to anything other than `certificateValidationMode="None"` i.e PeerTrust, I get an error when trying to call methods in the service from the client's environment:

> "At least one security token in the message could not be validated."

However, when I call the service and sign the message with my private key it works. So it seems like no validation is happening only checking for a valid cert signature.

Is there a way to validate that the signed message is indeed signed with a certificate that matches a certificate in my trusted stores using web.config or can this only be done in code?

Below is my web.config (names have been changed to protect the innocent):

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="CertificateBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" httpHelpPageEnabled="true" />
        <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="160" maxConcurrentInstances="160" maxConcurrentSessions="100" />
        <serviceCredentials>
          <serviceCertificate findValue="*.publiccert.com" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="TrustedPeople" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"  />          
          <clientCertificate>
            <authentication trustedStoreLocation="LocalMachine" certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" />
          </clientCertificate>
        </serviceCredentials>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>

    <binding name="CertHttpsBinding" messageEncoding="Mtom" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" transferMode="Buffered" receiveTimeout="10:01:00" sendTimeout="10:01:00" textEncoding="utf-8">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="1024" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>

  </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>

  <services>
    <service name="Test.Services.Service" behaviorConfiguration="CertificateBehavior">
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="http://test.com/Service.svc"/>
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
      <endpoint address=""
               binding="basicHttpBinding"
               bindingConfiguration="CertHttpsBinding"
               contract="Test.Services.TestService"
               bindingNamespace=""  />
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment  aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" >
    <serviceActivations>
      <add relativeAddress="~/Service.svc" service="Test.Services.Service" />
    </serviceActivations>
  </serviceHostingEnvironment>
</system.serviceModel>
```

my test client config:

```
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="testCertBehavior">
      <clientCredentials>
        <clientCertificate findValue="*.myPrivateCert" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="TrustedPeople" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
      </clientCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Test" sendTimeout="00:03:00"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          messageEncoding="Mtom">
  <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
    <message clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
  </security>
</binding>

<endpoint address="https://test.com/Service.svc"
       binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Test"
       contract="Test.Services.TestService" name="EndPoint_BasicHttpBinding_Test"
       behaviorConfiguration="testCertBehavior" />
```

Comment: What does the client config look like after you added the service reference?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @scheien I am not sure what my client's actual config looks like, but  this is my client set up for testing, question updated.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Thanks, although I was just trying to make the title more meaningful, and saw lots of other questions that referenced WCF in the title.

Comment: No big problem, but most readers looking for WCF questions will use the tag, not the title. It's a "separation of concerns" thing - the title should be data, not metadata.